# IF NOT EXIST and Insert mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert-into

hey guys can someone point me whats wrong in my mysql code
im trying to create a stored procedure called in a trigger 
were a user insert a new book in the books table, the bookqty table insert if callNumber does not exist and updates when exist, but in some point the insert query is not working
but the update query works fine
thank you in advance

```
use librarydb;
drop procedure if exists intoBooksQty;
delimiter $$

    create procedure intoBooksQty(in newcallNumber varchar(10))

        begin
            if not exists (select * from books where callNumber = newcallNumber) then
                insert into librarydb.bookqty(callNumber,bookQty,bookqtyOut) values (newcallNumber, 1,0);
            else
                update bookqty set bookQty = bookQty + 1 where callNumber = newCallNumber;
            end if;
        end$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: What error msg or behaviour are you getting when "it doesn't work". You must be clear and specific about the problem - see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make a UPSERT.

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `intoBooksQty`(`newcallNumber` VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `bookqty` (`callNumber`, `bookQty`, `bookqtyOut`)
  SELECT `newcallNumber`, 1, 0
  FROM `books`
  WHERE `callNumber` = `newcallNumber`
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `bookQty` = `bookQty` + 1;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22546/1)</kbd>

Comment: this works fine, tnx a lot sir, it helps a lot in my thesis XD